# Connecting to mysql using server IP address

Tags: java, mysql, connection

```
private DBHandler(String ServerIP, String userName, String password)
{
    DB_USERNAME = userName;
    DB_PASSWORD = password;

    DB_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://"+ServerIP+"/Test";
    connection = createConnetcion(DB_DRIVER, DB_CONNECTION_URL, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    System.out.println("Connection created");

}
```

when executing this code java sql exception occured."Host 'WS1A101.ushustech.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server".
Is any complaint for my code? what is exactly wrong here?

Comment: The question title is implying that the problem is caused by using an IP address. Why exactly? Does it work if you use a hostname instead or so?

Answer (score 2):

Have your DBA check that connections from your client machine are allowed to connect to the Database.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with code, ask your DBA to give your machine permission to connect to that database

Answer (score 0):

Unless your mysql account was created as `username@name_of_machine_you_connect_from` or `username@ip_of_machine_you_connect_from`, or uses a wildcard `username@%`, you won't be allowed to connect. If it is using the hostname version, make sure that there's a reverse DNS mapping in place, so mysql can map the IP address it sees back to the hostname that's listed in the user table.

Answer (score 0):

put `DB_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://ws1a101.ushustech.com/Test";`

instead of DB_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://"+ServerIP+"/Test";

Answer (score 0):

Your need to set permission for your host in MySQL. In your case it should be something like

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on Test.* to 'user'@'WS1A101.ushustech.com' identified by 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```